# Count how many events were each month

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I have a chart that I want to fill in with information about how many records I have every month. The chart needs to receive the data in such format:

```
    data: [
    ["Jan", 140],
    ["Feb", 240],
    ["Mar", 190],
    ["Apr", 140],
    ["May", 180],
    ["Jun", 320],
    ["Jul", 270],
    ["Aug", 180]
],
```

I need to generate how many records I had each month. my database looks like:

```
id |   start     |    end     |
------------------------------
1  |  2015-10-01 | 2015-10-31 |
2  |  2015-10-05 | 2015-10-09 |
3  |  2015-10-06 | 2015-10-07 |
4  |  2015-11-01 | 2015-11-02 |
5  |  2015-11-03 | 2015-11-06 |
6  |  2015-11-09 | 2015-10-13 |
7  |  2015-11-16 | 2015-10-18 |
8  |  2015-11-21 | 2015-10-29 |
```

So we have 3 records in October and 5 records in November.
How should I properly initialise a function that will eventually return me a proper looking format that I can pass to the data?
I can fetch records like

MODEL:

```
   function specialtest($start, $end) {
   $q = ("SELECT count(*) as count FROM reservations WHERE end > '$start' and start < '$end'");
   $query = $this->db->query($q);
   print json_encode($query->result_array());
   exit;
}
```

And then in the Controller:

```
   $data = $this->model->specialtest($arg, $arg2);
```

However this is not what I need exactly. I need those records each month without calling any function arguments as I don't know them? any ideas?

Comment: use sql statement or a view to retrieve data and php to show

Comment: @Ilan Hasanov : you want a sql query that retrieve the data that you want?

Comment: Did u try using `group by month` after you append the `count` as a column.

Comment: `i need those records each month without calling any function arguments as i don't know them` - good one :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope it helps...

```
function specialtest() {
$data = [];
$year = 2015;

for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++){
    $sql = 'SELECT count(*) as count FROM reservations WHERE YEAR(start) = '.$year.' AND MONTH(start)='.$i;
    $query =  $this->$db->query($sql);
    $results = $query->result_array();
    $data[] = [date('M', strtotime($year.'-'.$i.'-01')) => $results[0]['count']];
}

echo json_encode($data);
exit(); 
}
```

Comment: This is perfect! could you add some explnation? how it works, the $results[0] also seems a bit unclear

Comment: it is executing the sql for every month in $year and then adding the count result to data array by using month name as key. i wrote $results[0]['count'] because i don't know what you used for active records so i assumed $query->result_array() returns results as an array so getting sql result of count column should be as $results[0]['count'] and also i used $results[0] because query should have return only 1 row count.

Comment: this wont work next year though, it will always pull from 2015.

Comment: @Adunahay lol... function specialtest($year)... or $year = date('Y'); anyone can make this even beginners to php... it is like lesson 1.0.1

Answer (score 4):

As long as this function isnt being used elsewhere in the app, update the query to be something like this:

```
$q = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(start, '%b') as month, DATE_FORMAT(start, '%Y') as year, count(*) as count FROM reservations WHERE end > '$start' and start < '$end' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(start, '%b-%Y')";
```

note that you need to include the year so that next year you aren't grabbing entries from the previous year.

Comment: How should i use the $start, $end? as 2015:2015?